# Test if a subclass overrides a virtual function in a base class

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to check to see if a child class overrides a function on it's base class. Comparing member function pointers works perfectly fine if they aren't virtual, but if they *are* virtual it does not work. This sample code is essentially what I'm having trouble with.

```
class Base {
    public:

    virtual void vfoo(){ cout << "foo"; }
    virtual void vbar(){ cout << "bar"; }
    void foo(){ cout << "foo"; }
    void bar(){ cout << "bar"; }
};

class Child : public Base {
    public:

    void vfoo(){ cout << "foo2"; }
    void foo(){ cout << "foo2"; }
};

int main (){
    //non-virtual cases, these work correctly
    cout << (&Base::foo == &Child::foo) << endl; //outputs false (good)
    cout << (&Base::bar == &Child::bar) << endl; //outputs true  (good)

    //virtual cases, these do not work correctly
    cout << (&Base::vfoo == &Child::vfoo) << endl; //outputs true (BAD, child::vfoo and base::vfoo are DIFFERENT FUNCTIONS)
    cout << (&Base::vbar == &Child::vbar) << endl; //outputs true (good, child::vbar and base::vbar are the same)

    return 0;
}
```

Logically there's no reason this shouldn't work, but the C++ spec says otherwise (comparing virtual functions addresses this way is implementation defined).

On GCC, type punning &Base::vfoo and &Child::vfoo to int has them both be "1" (and vbar is "9"), which look to be vtable offsets. The following code appears to correctly get the function addresses out of the vtable, and correctly reports different addresses for Child::vfoo and Base::bfoo, and the same address for vbar

```
template<typename A, typename B>
A force_cast(B in){
    union {
        A a;
        B b;
    } u;
    u.b = in;
    return u.a;
};

template<typename T>
size_t get_vtable_function_address_o(T* obj, int vtable_offset){
    return *((size_t*)((*(char**)obj + vtable_offset-1)));
};

template<typename T, typename F>
size_t get_vtable_function_address(T* obj, F function){
    return get_vtable_function_address_o(obj, force_cast<size_t>(function));
};


int main (){
    Base* a = new Base();
    Base* b = new Child();

    cout << get_vtable_function_address(a, &Base::vfoo) << endl; 
    cout << get_vtable_function_address(b, &Base::vfoo) << endl; 

    cout << get_vtable_function_address(a, &Base::vbar) << endl; 
    cout << get_vtable_function_address(b, &Base::vbar) << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine on GCC, though the fact that I have to subtract 1 from the vtable offset for it to work seems a bit weird. But it doesn't work on microsoft's compiler (punning &Base::vfoo to a size_t returns some garbage instead of a virtual table offset) (some experimenting here suggests that the correct offsets here would be 0 for vfoo and 4 for vbar)

I am WELL AWARE that this stuff is implementation-defined, but I am hoping there is a way to do this that at least works on a few common compilers (gcc, msvc, and clang) since vtables are pretty standard at this point (even if it requires compiler-specific code)?

Is there any way to do this?

Note 1: I only need this to work on single inheritance. I don't use multiple or virtual inheritance

Note 2: Re-emphasizing that I do not need a callable function, I only need to test if a child class has overwritten a specific virtual function. If there's a way to do this without needing to dig into the vtables for stuff, then that would be preferred.

Comment: Try a dynamic_cast to what you want to compare it to and if that fails then you know its not using it.

Comment: Read https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible. It's old but sheds some light on the matter.

Comment: A key benefit of virtual functions is that your code is shielded from knowing whether or not the function has been overridden. Trying to fight this strikes me as a design flaw earlier in the process. ([XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?)

Comment: @JaMiT I have a list of objects of a specific base class. Not all of them implement every virtual function, so for an optimization I could, for instance, store a separate list for each function, so if I want to call "update" on all objects it would only need to loop over the ones that actually implemented "update", instead of the entire list of objects (which would contain many where that function is just a do-nothing placeholder)

Comment: A do-nothing placeholder does not take much time to execute, does it? You have tested and confirmed that this optimization is actually measurably effective? It could be a lot of work for no noticeable benefit. (Hmm... maybe if the placeholder actually did something - like return a distinctive value - you could detect when it was called without a lot of hacking. Maybe the placeholder aspect should make it into the question?)

Comment: it matters a lot if theres 100000 objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++11 and over, comparing function types by `decltype` and `std::is_same`, we can get the desired results.
(If C++11 is not available for you, you can still use `typeid` and `operator==(const type_info& rhs)` for this purpose.)

---

Since `Base::vfoo` is overridden by `Child`, the type of `decltype(&Child::vfoo)` is `void (Child::*)()` and different from `decltype(&Base::vfoo)` which is `void (Base::*)()`.
Thus

```
std::is_same<decltype(&Base::vfoo) , decltype(&Child::vfoo)>::value
```

is `false`.

( In fact, in the clause 4 of C++ standard draft n3337 which enumerates the set of implicit conversions, *4.11 Pointer to member conversions [conv.mem] / 2*,

> 2. A prvalue of type “pointer to member of B of type cv T”, where B is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv T”, where D is a derived class (Clause 10) of B. If B is an inaccessible (Clause 11), ambiguous (10.2), or virtual (10.1) base class of D, or a base class of a virtual base class of D, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The result of the conversion refers to the same member as the pointer to member before the conversion took place, but it refers to the base class member as if it were a member of the derived class. The result refers to the member in D’s instance of B. Since the result has type “pointer to member of D of type cv T”, it can be dereferenced with a D object. The result is the same as if the pointer to member of B were dereferenced with the B subobject of D. The null member pointer value is converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type.

, states that the implicit conversion from `decltype(&Base::vfoo)` to `decltype(&Child::vfoo)` can be legal but does not mention the one of the reverse direction.
In addition, *5.2.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast] / 12*,

> 12. A prvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type *cv1* T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to
>       member of B” of type *cv2* T, where B is a base class (Clause 10) of D, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to member of B of type T” to “pointer to member of D of type T” exists (4.11), and *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*. Then null member pointer value(4.11) is converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type. If class B contains the original member, or is a base or derived class of the class containing the original member, the resulting pointer to member points to the original member. Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined. [*Note*: although class B need not contain the original member, the dynamic type of the object on which the pointer to member is dereferenced must contain the original member; see 5.5. — *end note* ]

, states that the explicit conversion using `static_cast` from `decltype(&Child::vfoo)` to `decltype(&Base::vfoo)` can also be legal.
Then legal casts with each other in this case are

```
void (Child::*pb)() = &Base::vfoo;
void (Base ::*pc)() = static_cast<void(Base::*)()>(&Child::vfoo);
```

and this `static_cast` means that the types of `&Base::vfoo` and `&Child::vfoo` are different with each other without any explicit cast.)

---

OTOH, since `Base::vbar` is not overridden by `Child`, the type of `decltype(&Child::vbar)` is `void (Base::*)()` and same with `decltype(&Base::vbar)`.
Thus

```
std::is_same<decltype(&Base::vbar) , decltype(&Child::vbar)>::value
```

is `true`.

( It seems that *5.3.1 Unary operators [expr.unary.op] / 3* of n3337,

> 3. The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-
>      id*. If the operand is a *qualified-id* naming a non-static member m of some class C with type T, the result has type “pointer to member of class C of type T” and is a prvalue designating C::m. Otherwise, if the type of the expression is T, the result has type “pointer to T” and is a prvalue that is the address of the designated object (1.7) or a pointer to the designated function. [ Note: In particular, the address of an object of type “*cv* T” is “pointer to *cv* T”, with the same cv-qualification. — end note ] [ Example:
>
>    ```
>    struct A { int i; };
>    struct B : A { };
>    ... &B::i ...       // has type int A::*
>    ```
>
>    — end example ]

, states this behavior.
Interesting discussion of this paragraph is also found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#203).)

---

In summary, we can check whether each member function is overridden or not using `decltype(&Base::...)`, `decltype(&Child::...)` and `std::is_same` as follows:

[**Live DEMO (GCC / Clang / ICC / VS2017)**](https://godbolt.org/z/qRR9fc)

```
// Won't fire.
static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(&Base::foo) , decltype(&Child::foo)> ::value, "oops.");

// Won't fire.
static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(&Base::bar) , decltype(&Child::bar)> ::value, "oops.");

// Won't fire.
static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(&Base::vfoo), decltype(&Child::vfoo)>::value, "oops.");

// Won't fire.
static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(&Base::vbar), decltype(&Child::vbar)>::value, "oops.");
```

---

BTW, we can also define the following macro to make these easer:

```
#define IS_OVERRIDDEN(Base, Child, Func)                                 \
(std::is_base_of<Base, Child>::value                                     \
 && !std::is_same<decltype(&Base::Func), decltype(&Child::Func)>::value)
```

which then let us write

```
static_assert( IS_OVERRIDDEN(Base, Child, foo) , "oops."); // Won't fire.
static_assert(!IS_OVERRIDDEN(Base, Child, bar) , "oops."); // Won't fire.
static_assert( IS_OVERRIDDEN(Base, Child, vfoo), "oops."); // Won't fire.
static_assert(!IS_OVERRIDDEN(Base, Child, vbar), "oops."); // Won't fire.
```